# Nikon D600/D800 support for manual lenses with adapter

Tags: lens-adapter, compatibility, nikon-d600, nikon-d800, nikon-d3200

I am considering buying a **Nikon D600 or a D800**.

I have some old manual lenses, most of them have Pentacon Six a.k.a. Kiev 60 mounts. On my **Nikon D3200** I was able to use these lenses with adapters (such as Pentacon-to-Nikon and Arax Tilt), in manual mode.

I assume that those adapted lenses behave in a same way as pre-AI Nikkor lenses, right?

But recently, I encountered [this chart](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/compatibility-lens.htm#dslr) which states that pre-AI lenses would not mount on D600/D800, while they would mount on a D3200. I found no exact description anywhere, why a D3200 would mount a wider spectrum of lenses than a D600/D800.

Now the question: **Is my assumption true, that an old adapted lens is technically a pre-AI lens, thus being unusable on a D600/D800?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer to your question is: no.

Long answer to your question is: The chart from Ken Rockwell is specific to Nikkor lenses, not lenses with appropriate adapters for modern F-mount cameras. Given that Nikon is a significant brand, there are quite a few adapters from various lens mounts to the modern F-mount, including the Pentacon Six, as you discovered. The [Fotodiox adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001G4P9ZK) should be fine. For further details on options with other lens, including other medium format lenses, see this guide: [Master Guide to Rigging a Nikon D800 or D800E](http://wolfcrow.com/blog/master-guide-to-rigging-a-nikon-d800-or-d800e-part-1/) which includes some information to reassure you that you're good to go.

Comment: Finally got an D800 ;) I tried out a simple non-electronic M42-to-Nikon adapter. It works! So, you're right. Thank you for the answer.